# plugin form for multi member information

Tags: wordpress, forms, plugins, responsive

I want to have a form that
user click on a sign to the number of members of their group.
And then  specific fields are display to the number of members of the group
to user enter member information.
Is there a plugin for this?
Better if it's free and responsive.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Contact Form 7](https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/) to create the form and then use [Contact Form 7 Conditional Fields](https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-conditional-fields/) to display fields based on certain conditions.

[image]